# Rendering Blender 2.79 on MAC PRO (late 2013)

Tags: rendering, opencl

I have been not that active with Blender lately, but I am trying to catch up with current development by installing Blender 2.79. Reading about all the improvements related to OpenCL I wonder what is the status quo for AMD GPU's on Mac Pro (AMD FirePro D300, D500, D700).

I have difficulty to understand wether all these OpenCL improvement are also noticeable when working with these GPU's and if you have to do something special for having these benefits ?

When reading [this](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Render/Cycles/OpenCL) ... I am not sure what to expect on AMD Firepro?

> Testing Activate OpenCL rendering For AMD cards on Windows and Linux
>   you just need to select your GPU under file -> user preferences ->
>   system. The split kernel will be used by default to give the best
>   performance. To use OpenCL on other platforms, launch Blender with
>   --debug-value 256 (either on the command line or by adding it to your shortcut). It will add a section "debug" in the render options panel.
>   There you can choose the kernel (split or mega) and the platform (set
>   to "all" to enable OpenCL for Intel and NVidia). Then choose GPU as
>   the device to render in the render option panel.

Comment: What is there to answer? You get most of your info on the "Whats new" page, even some performance numbers: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Cycles#OpenCL. You can see that now both APIs support full feature sets: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/features.html. You can guess the rendering speed of a GPU by it's 32bit float compute performance (compare to something you know the results of). On Mac the drivers are crippled though, AMD is working on fixing them as it seems Apple doesn't care.

Comment: I think you say that running Blender with AMD should give likewise performance as running with NVIDIA/CUDA but that things on MAC are still shit. Is that what you are saying ? Because I have difficulty to draw conclusions when I read those documents. So if you understand the status quo of Mac OpenCL then you explanation is appreciated. I understand that generally speaking on AMD OpenCL things have improved but what is the MAC situation ?

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test on so I can't confirm, but you are right. There is no info I could find that the matter is resolved on Mac, so my deduction is it is still limited. You can boot Linux on Mac, so even if MacOS is crippled, you should be able to render under Linux fine. I don't expect those FirePro gpus to be any good though.